# In ASP.net, am I adding the header code correctly?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reporting-services

I found a good [tutorial(which is cached by google)](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aECpKFBcqCjkJ%3awww.rajbandi.net/category/Reporting-Services.aspx%20&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) that shows how to fix the date-picker in SSRS. It tells me to

> Add the below script in the html head section

So, because this is an ASPX website there's no HTML file, and I assume I should add it into my Default.aspx page, like so:

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
if ($.browser.webkit) { 
$($(":hidden[id*='DatePickers']").val().split(",")).each(function(i, item){ 
var h = $("table[id*='ParametersGrid'] span").filter(function(i) { 
var v = "[" + $(this).text() + "]"; 
return (v != null && v.indexOf(item) >= 0); }).parent("td").next("td").find("input").datepicker({ showOn: "button" ,buttonImage: '/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.calendar.gif' ,buttonImageOnly: true ,dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' ,changeMonth: true ,changeYear: true }); }); } }); 
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

However, this is not working correctly(the date-picker still is not clickable/workin).

What does the `($.browser.webkit)` code mean?  Do i need to import in my own JS datepicker(I found a few different datepickers online)  ?

thanks!

Comment: `$.browser.webkit` will be non-falsy is the browser is webkit based, like Chrome, Safari etc.

Comment: non-falsy , what do you mean> ? so it's a defualt thing in chrome/safari

Comment: means `if($.browser.webkit)` will pass, and statements inside the `if` will get executed.

Comment: Oh i see . Hmm, I guess It should be easy to test that

Comment: Yes. Put an `alert('I am webkit')` inside the `if` and test using different browsers. Non-webkit (ex: FF, IE) shouldn't show the alert.

Comment: @techfoobar - OK cool, so i know there's another issue with my code, because in google-Chrome it's not popping the alert text.. I'll study my code!